# Does adb pull verify files automatically?

Tags: adb, file-transfer, files

Does adb pull verify files automatically? For instance, does it check the hash/checksum of pulled files to see whether they were pulled correctly? I'm guessing it does, but I haven't found an answer online.

If not, I can write a bash script (Linux) for it and post it in an answer.

Comment: This link about [verify your file's MD5 checksums!](http://androidforums.com/threads/verify-your-files-md5-checksums.138831/) might be helpful for verifying your file integrity  after the adb pull command. As mentioned on that post, _You can actually view a file's MD5 checksum using Astro File Manager (i.e., via viewing a file's details)_ and the command `adb shell md5sum FILE` also seems to be helpful to check the checksum of a file. Read more on the above mentioned link for other methods too ;)

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a Bash (Linux) script that runs `adb pull` and then compares the md5sums of the pulled files with the original files. If the md5sums don't match, the script will automatically remove the corrupted pulled files and then retry `adb pull` again. I put the script on Pastebin [here](http://pastebin.com/r7PinvDL) (thanks to the tip from [GiantTree](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/86358/gianttree)).

Comment: Could you upload it to pastebin as well, so users can see the script instantly without downloading it first?

Comment: Hey I can't believe I didn't think to do that! Sure!

Answer (score 2):

From what I have seen so far (and I use `adb pull` very often), there is no verification process going on.
If a file, that has been pulled, is corrupted, you will get *no* notification about it whatsoever.

Comment: Even if there is no verification in the UI, that doesn't necessarily mean ADB isn't doing a verification behind the scenes, so I'm curious if you mean that you have indeed had files corrupted on download, that when redownloaded were fine? (Thank you if you have sometime to reply when next you log on.)